# importing @types/jquery throws tons of errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, webpack, definitelytyped

I have a project using angular 2 and typescript, being built with webpack. I am trying to move jquery into my package management instead of using a script tag in the header. (this is so I am able to "namespace" my jquery. my app gets run on other pages.)

I import jQuery `import * as $ from "jquery"` but get "cannot find module jquery." So I install @types/jquery, but get a ton of errors. Most are "duplicate identifier" errors. I have tried some suggestiong using jqueryFactory, or something similar, but to no avail.

It seems I am stuck with either duplicate identifier errors, or jquery undefined. I really just need to reference jquery once to stick it to the window with a different name other than `$` or `jQuery`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `window["$"] = window["jQuery"] = require("jquery")`

Comment: I believe that you installed the `@types/jquery` package of version 3.2. This version requires TypeScript of version 2.3+. Perhaps, your project uses an older TS version. Upgrade it to the latest one. Does this resolve the issue? If not, send me a project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Oh man this was it. I could not find this anywhere. If you write this in an answer, I will accept it.